# Procedure (unknown) does not exist PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm new to PostgreSQL, and trying to learn about stored procedure with PostgreSQL. Here are the steps I followed.

1. Installed pgAdmin4
2. Created the Database
3. Created the table "Users" under public schema
4. Created the procedure "GetUserByEmail"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetUserByEmail  
(      
   Email Varchar(100)
)

LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  
$$  
BEGIN         

 Select * from public."Users" where "Email" = Email
END  
$$;
```

When calling it from query tool, I get an error.

```
CALL public.GetUserByEmail('d@d.com')
```

> ERROR:  procedure public.getuserbyemail(unknown) does not exist LINE
> 1: CALL public.GetUserByEmail('d@d.com')
>
> ^ HINT:  No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. SQL state: 42883
> Character: 6

Checked the permission, and the user has execution rights.

Tried different ways but not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Get rid of the **MixedCase names** (or double-quote them)

Comment: A procedure isn't meant to return a result. You should use a function instead.

Comment: @wildplasser If I don't use double quote, it gives me some other error like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5H3O.png

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Okay, seems like SP works differently here than SQL server!

Comment: Yes, Postgres is **very** different to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
if you `create table "users"(a int...)` then you stick with **"users"** every time you select/update/delete `"users"` table.

You can easily imitate `38.5.9. SQL Functions Returning Sets`(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html)

```
CREATE FUNCTION getusers(text) RETURNS SETOF "users" AS $$
    SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE email = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM getusers('hi') AS t1;
```

[stored procedure versus function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118418/when-to-use-stored-procedure-user-defined-function/118419#118419)
[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b86a36f9db52fd47e47b605a34432983)